# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:

Tags: java

I know that simillar questions have been asked, but they all had the same problem: inside of the loop they had something like

```
i <= aString.lenth()
```

I used

```
i < phrase.length();
```

and I'm still getting the error. I also tried

```
i < phrase.length()-1;
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Thanks.

```
public class WordPlay {
    public boolean isVowel(char c) {
        if(c=='a' || c=='A' || c=='e' || c=='E' || c=='i' || c=='I' || c=='o' || c=='O' ||     c=='u' || c=='U') {    
            return true;
        }    
        else
        {
            return false;
        }    
    }
    public void testIsVowel () {
        System.out.println(isVowel('F'));
    }
    public String replaceVowels (String phrase, char ch){
        StringBuilder replaced = new StringBuilder(phrase);
        for (int i = 0; i<phrase.length(); i++) {
            char currChar = phrase.charAt(i);
            if (isVowel(currChar)){

                    //the line below causes the error
                    replaced.setCharAt(currChar, ch);
            }    
        }    
        return replaced.toString();    
    }
    public void testReplaceVowels() {
        System.out.println(replaceVowels("Hello World", '*'));

    }    
}
```

Comment: @JohnSmith the error is in the title - java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:

Comment: Which line is giving you the error? Please [edit] your question and include the relevant part of the stack trace.

Comment: At wich iteration does it happen?

Comment: @LutzHorn it is included - there is a comment above it.

Comment: That is the error message. But it must include the line number where it happens. Which line is causing the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your call to [`StringBuilder.setCharAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt-int-char-)

```
replaced.setCharAt(currChar, ch);
```

the first argument should be `i`, not `currChar`:

```
replaced.setCharAt(i, ch);
```

You should pass **the index** you want to set the char at, **not the character itself**.

`currChar`'s `int` value is probably higher than the length of your `StringBuilder`, which caused the exception, but if it wasn't, you would get strange output without an exception, which is even worse.

Comment: Thanks so much, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is the **setCharAt method** of **AbstractStringBuilder** class.

```
public void setCharAt(int index, char ch) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= count))
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    value[index] = ch;
}
```

If you are passing character **'a'** to setCharAt method, it will be implicitly cast from character to **int value 97 at index** .
It made **java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException**.  Thanks :)